# Call webservice with parameter in AngularJS

Tags: json, angularjs, web-services

How call webservice with parameter in angularjs and get resault

My web service is  http:// mysite.com/service.asmx/users  + two parameter username and password.

whether it be something like this

```
<script>
    var app = angular.module("myApp",[]);
    app.controller("usersCtrl",function submit($scope,$http){
        var username = "test";
        var password=  "test";

         var url = 'http:// mysite.com/service.asmx/users';
                //???????????
    });
</script>
```

Comment: How do your webservice want to receive that data?

Comment: @Rodmentou  service return { "records":[ {"Name":"Alfreds Futterkiste","City":"Berlin","Country":"Germany"}] }

Comment: @Rodmentou  I want display ex. Name and city in <ul><li> list

Comment: Yes, yes. I want to know how does the server handle the incoming request. Does it read headers, body or request params? Depending on how you want to receive data on your server, you'll need to change the way you send data within you Angular app.

Comment: @Rodmentou I don't understend your question please see my service here http://postimg.org/image/rsru5kizb/

Comment: Have you tried @JonStevens answer?

Comment: @Rodmentou not working

Comment: And I still don't understand your question. Sorry, I'm leaving. :/

Answer (score 0):

You should use an angular service to accomplish this. But, with your current controller, you would call:

> var result = $http.get(url + username + "/" + password);